# Where does the Adobe AIR Browser store it's cache?

Tags: caching, air

When you create a AIR app with an embedded web browser, where does it store it's cache?  How can I clear this cache?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my WinXP machine, AIR apps cache such data into `C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files`. So while I don't have any other systems to hand, it would appear AIR uses what it considers to be the platform-specific system temp folder. (As for how you clear it, in my case you can do so through IE settings dialogs or other "clean up unused data" dialogs elsewhere in the OS, so I imagine it's similar on other platforms.)

If that doesn't help, can you post your OS?