# Where does the Adobe AIR Browser store it's cache on ubuntu?

Tags: air, adobe

I tried removing and reinstalling Adobe Air SDK. but adobe air client still getting my old login information.

This link seems to be only for Windows
[Where does the Adobe AIR Browser store it's cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829215/where-does-the-adobe-air-browser-store-its-cache)

Comment: On Win and Mac AIR uses the default browsers data, so on Windows I go in IE and clear the browser history, can you check clearing the browser history in Firefox in Ubuntu?

Comment: @simion314 Thanks for suggestion. But could not help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ubuntu the location was :

```
$/home/$username$/.appdata/myapp
```

A directory was there with appname

```
$myapp/Local Store/

$ls 
db  #SharedObjects
rm -rf db  #SharedObjects
```

This worked :)